# How does Armor Penetration works with Critical Hits?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm wondering if there is any advantage obtained with Critical Damage having Last Whisper as item.

Will the Armor Penetration work directly with the total Critical Damage? Or there's some calculations to pass through?

I've been using Shaco almost 7 out of 10 ranked games atm to get to Platinum Tier, and it's really an issue for me since Critical Damage is one of Shaco's 'bread and butter' and I've been experimenting on different set of items each game.

Comment: It works the exact same as normal damage with armor pen - crit only means you do more damage on your attack

Comment: It's also dependent on your target. If they have a lot of armor early in the game the last whisper will be more useful than if you rushed a ghostblade. Otherwise a ghostblade rush is actually pretty good on shaco because he benefits from all its stats.

Comment: Oh, I see. I usually think 'Critical Damages' do true damage since most of the times, when I play as tank, I receive high damage from crits (usually from ADR) even if they don't have LW with me having around 250+ armor.

Comment: If you have the 10% crit reduction mastery and ninja tabi, most adc's won't even be able to tickle you.

Comment: If youre looking to carry as Shaco, buy a Trifoce->IE and 1shot their adc from behind every fight.

Answer (score 3):

The crit damage is counted like "normal" attack damage after armor penetration and reduction, just modified by your crit multiplier.

[When attacking, armor penetration and armor reduction are considered in the following order](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_penetration#Order_of_calculations):

1. Armor reduction, flat
2. Armor reduction, percentage
3. Armor penetration, percentage
4. Armor penetration, flat

Answer (score 1):

so the way this works if fairly simple.

1. your attack does a set amount of damage
2. this damage is reduced by their armor or magic resist (depending on the ability or attack used).
3. critical damage is applied. (200% normally but Lord vann damm's pillager increases this to 250% which is very useful for a character like shaco)

hope this helped ya :)

Answer (score 0):

Armor penetration and critical damage **stack multiplicatively**, which means they combine well and it is **efficient to focus on both** at the same time.

If a normal attack would deal 100 dmg (no crit, no arpen) but 150 dmg with arpen (still no crit), doing a critical hit with that same arpen on the same target will deal 150*crit_multiplier (ex : 200%)

Since you talked about **Shaco** in particuliar, be aware that his Q (Deceive) is guaranteed to make you land a critical hit, but at rank 1, the crit is a modified 140% damage multiplier instead of 200% standart. Riot has stated that they consider it a regular crit, only the damage multiplier is modified to make it balanced. Other critical damage modifiers still work on Shaco's Q, like Infinity Edge and crit damage runes. [Here is a post from Riot Guinsoo about it](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=144267&highlight=shaco%20crit%20damage&page=2#post1700131), it's from 2010 but the idea is the same as of patch 4.10. I just wanted to remind everyone that, because the tooltip isn't very accurate, but you probably already know if you play Shaco a lot.